# how to pass HashMap<String, Object>from one activity to another

Tags: java, android-studio

my current code in the first activity is

```
    public final static String doctorDataKEY        = "asLSAD654sdf";

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_Doctor.class);
            //passing values to user activity
            intent.putExtra(doctorDataKEY, (Parcelable) data);
```

and in the second activity its

```
    private Map<String, Object> doctorData = new HashMap<>();

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        doctorData = (Map<String, Object>) intent.getSerializableExtra(Activity_Doctor_Login.doctorDataKEY);
```

it does not show any error in the code but when i ran the app it just crash when i press the button.

i think the code would've worked if its Map <String,String> but since its a data set from firestore i believe i have to use Map<String,Object>.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `putExtra()` this method adds extras as `Parcellable` and in the second activity, you are getting extras from `Serializable`. So the value will be null, and since you are casting it as `HashMap<>` it is throwing a class cast exception.

you need to use this

```
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(Activity_Doctor_Login.doctorDataKEY)
```

instead of `intent.getSerializableExtra(Activity_Doctor_Login.doctorDataKEY)`

Comment: i just tried it and i'm getting a new error as java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable. is there another way to pass it?

Comment: can you use put serializableExtra() method instead of putExtra() in FirstActivity?

Comment: make sure you all class implements serializable